# How to configure WebRTC with Coturn and oAuth

Tags: oauth, webrtc, stun, turn, rfc5766turnserver

I want to use [coturn with oAuth](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/turnserver#user-content-third-party-authorizationauthentication-support-with-oauth). If I understood it correctly I need to do two things:

- Storing the oAuth tokens in the database coturn is using
- Sending the `ACCESS-TOKEN` and `USERNAME` STUN attributes

First point is clear but how do I need to change my WebRTC client to achieve the second point?

Without oAuth I would initialize my `RTCPeerConnection` like this:

```javascript
var configuration = {
  'iceServers': [{
    'url': 'turn:turn.example.org',
    'username': 'user',
    'credential': 'password'
  }]
};
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration)
```

The [WebRTC 1.0 draft](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#h-rtcicecredentialtype-enum) defines a `RTCIceCredentialType` enum so i would think I need to change my configuration like this:

```javascript
var configuration = {
  'iceServers': [{
    'url': 'turn:turn.example.org',
    'username': 'kid',
    'credential': 'oAuthToken',
    'credentialType': 'token'
  }]
};
```

Using Wireshark I can't see the `ACESS-TOKEN` attribute. Any ideas or does anyone know a working example?

Comment: what is the command you are using to start the TURN server?

Comment: `turnserver -n -f -v -l stdout -a --oauth -r "myRealm" -J "myMongoConnection"`

Comment: I am guessing you are getting `401` error in the TURN server logs

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You're right, the error is: `26: session 005000000000000001: realm <myRealm> user <my<user>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unknown error
26: check_stun_auth: user turn credentials are incorrect`. I thought that coturn is using long term credentials here because the `ACCESS-TOKEN` attribute is not sent.

Comment: I was trying it out for the last two days,  was getting similar error, but I did not have an oauth setup, used a redis server, and manually added rows in it

Comment: for my project, I use TURN auth secret, so need dependency on database, but hook is the system time of your server and that of WebRTC must be nearly similar

Comment: my guess is, you must pass the `mac_key` as credential, also for some reason, suspect that it is checking the table `turnusers_lt` instead of `oauth_key` then again, I am only guessing.

Comment: Are you using the coturn REST API or oauth? The auth secret is only used for the REST API as far as I know. I'm also manually adding oauth keys to my DB and sending the `ikm_key` value as credential. My guess is that it's checking `turnusers_lt` because my client doesn't tell that he wants to use oauth because the credential is not passed as `ACCESS-TOKEN`. My guess is that the client is doing it wrong not the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85180/discussion-between-mido22-and-lefloh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like things changed a bit since original question was asked. The  [webrtc-pc#1033](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/pull/1033) pull-request alters the spec and introduces the following `iceServers` configuration syntax:

```
var configuration = {
    'iceServers': [{
        "urls": "turns:turn.example.net",
        "username": "username",
        "credential": {
            "macKey": "...",
            "accessToken": "..."
        },
        "credentialType": "oauth"
    }],
    ...
}
```

See [`RTCIceServer`](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtciceserver-dictionary) documentation page for more configuration examples.

Comment: Sadly, `"credentialType": "oauth"` was [removed from the spec](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/pull/2362) and [turned into an extension](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-extensions/issues/18) because it was "at risk".  :(